# VB.Net forms application database table update

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to make a small application allowing users to read the content of a table describing the inventory of a warehouse, search depending on 2 rows indicating which warehouse the item resides in and by it's assigned barcode which i already managed to get to work by using a binding source, and a datagrid view, updating the view trough a query taking the barcode and location as strings from two boxes.

The second part i would need for this application to suit my basic objective would be to have a way to add new lines and store them into the original table on the database so users could add the new items independently from the warehouses directly.

So far i have encountered 2 issues: i need a primary key that would represent a sequential ID but i do not know how to produce a sequentially incrementing ID, i manage to get the first addition ID by using a `top 1 order by desc` query combination but the data does not get updated after adding the new line, producing an error since it tries to add another line with the same value for the primary key.
The second issue i am encountering is: the gridview gets altered accordingly to the data i input in the textboxes i set up to gather the various values for the table but the table on the database itself is not showing any change, keeping only the test data i inputted at it's creation.

```
Public Class AddItems
    Private Sub AddItems_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazzinoDataSet.LastUsedID' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.LastUsedIDTableAdapter.LastUsedID(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.LastUsedID)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazzinoDataSet.Stock' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StockTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.Stock)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazzinoDataSet.AddWarehouseList' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.AddWarehouseListTableAdapter.AddWarehouseList(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.AddWarehouseList)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazzinoDataSet.WarehouseList' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.WarehouseListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.WarehouseList)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazzinoDataSet.Stock' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StockTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.Stock)
    End Sub
     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim R As DataRow = MagazzinoDataSet.Tables("Stock").NewRow()

    R("Supplier") = Supplier.Text
    R("Producer_code") = ProducerCode.Text
    R("Barcode") = Barcode.Text
    R("Comp_name") = ComponentName.Text
    R("Warehouse") = Warehouse.Text
    R("Internal_Code") = InternalCode.Text
    R("Description_IT") = ITDescr.Text
    R("Description_EN") = ENDescr.Text
    'R("ID") = NextID.SelectedValue <- this would be an hidden uneditable multibox containing the product of the query finding the next value to be inserted in the table (basically last ID + 1, nothing fancy)"ID" would be the primary key of this table
    R("Quantity") = "0"

    MagazzinoDataSet.Tables("Stock").Rows.Add(R)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MagazzinoDataSet.Stock

End Sub
End Class
```

To sum it up:

- How would i go about updating the database table to include the new line?
- Is there a smart way to find the last value, incrementing it by 1 to have the next value and updating it when inserting a new line, so as to not end up with 2 lines with the same value for primary key, generating an error?

Comment: you can use `IDENTITY` for the purpose of incrementing primary key [further read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an incremental ID in the Db, assuming you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, in Design of the table, for the ID column, in Column Properties, scroll down to Identity Specification and set (is Identity) to Yes.

To add a new row, I use this code:

```
Using NotesDS As New DataSet
    Using NotesDA As New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = SQLDBConnection, .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE ID = " & ID}}
        NotesDA.Fill(NotesDS, "Notes")
        Using NotesDV As New DataView(NotesDS.Tables("Notes"))
            Using NoteBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(NotesDA) With {.QuotePrefix = "[", .QuoteSuffix = "]"}                        
                If NotesDV.Count = 0 Then                             
                    Dim NoteDRV As DataRowView = NotesDV.AddNew                       
                    NoteDRV.Item("UserName") = UserName
                    NoteDRV.Item("Note") = Note
                    NoteDRV.Item("NoteDate") = NoteDate
                    NoteDRV.Item("CompanyCode") = CompanyCode
                    NoteDRV.EndEdit()
                    NotesDA.UpdateCommand = NoteBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
                    NotesDA.Update(NotesDS, "Notes")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Obviously, amend to make appropriate for your table and column names.

If you need to retrieve the ID for display, you can add a handler to the Update like:

```
Public Sub GenericOnRowUpdated(sender As Object, e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)        
    Dim newID As Integer = 0
    Dim idCMD As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", SQLDBConnection)
    If e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then            
        newID = CInt(idCMD.ExecuteScalar())
        e.Row("ID") = newID
    End If
End Sub
```

and use like:

```
 AddHandler NotesDA.RowUpdated, New SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf GenericOnRowUpdated)
 NotesDA.Update(NotesDS, "Notes")
 NewID = NoteDRV.Item("ID")
```

**EDIT**

First Example amended and explained below:

```
'Declare you connection to the SQL dB. Connection String looks like "Data Source=192.168.71.10\dBName; Initial Catalog=dBName; User ID=USER; Password='PASSWORD!';MultipleActiveResultSets=true"  -  You may well already have an open connection, and can use that instead. Not sure what your 
StockBindingSource is...
    Dim oConn As New SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING")
    'Open the connection
    oConn.Open()
    'Declare Your DataAdapter and initialise using your connection
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = oConn, .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE ID=0"}}
    'Declare you DataSet
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    'Fill Your DataSet with the Stock table from your DataAdapter
    DA.Fill(DS, "Stock")
    'Declare a DataView for easy use (really the same as using DS.Tables("Stock").DefaultView)
    Dim DV As New DataView(DS.Tables("Stock"))
    'Declare a CommandBuilder and initialise with your DataAdapter. This will now watch for changes made to your data and build the appropriate SQL UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE command. the "[" and "]" are in case any column names use reserved words
    Dim Builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(DA) With {.QuotePrefix = "[", .QuoteSuffix = "]"}
    'Decalre a DataRowView for data population, based on your DataView table structure
    Dim R As DataRowView = DV.AddNew()
    'Populate the fileds with your Form data
    R("Supplier") = Supplier.Text
    R("Producer_code") = ProducerCode.Text
    R("Barcode") = Barcode.Text
    R("Comp_name") = ComponentName.Text
    R("Warehouse") = Warehouse.Text
    R("Internal_Code") = InternalCode.Text
    R("Description_IT") = ITDescr.Text
    R("Description_EN") = ENDescr.Text
    R("Quantity") = "0"
    'Notify that the edit has finished
    R.EndEdit()
    'Get the SQL command from the CommandBuilder 
    DA.UpdateCommand = Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
    'Execute the update (in this case it will be an INSERT) 
    DA.Update(DS, "Stock")
```

Comment: The variable ID is already set as identity on the DB.
I encountered issues when assigning the row value for ID since it should not have the same value twice. leaving it empty tried to assign a null to it which also resulted in an error.
I am trying to understand how to use your example to update the database table meanwhile, i usually used the stock datasources so i am having a hard time comparing and figuring out what exactly all the using mean and if i need them

Comment: You should be able to leave empty... you mentioned that your new rows are not getting added to the actual dB. I think the issue lies here - as the data is not getting pushed to the dB., the new ID is never assigned. Try amending the `Button1_Click` code similar to my example to see if this performs the update, and if the update is performe does this get rid of your NULL ID issue.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see your edit 'til now. Each Using is just so the variable doesn't stick around and is disposed of when finished - you can get rid of the Using..End Using and replace with Dim if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: Did you populate your `MagazzinoDataSet` using an `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: In order to read from it i used a StockTableAdapter with fills.
In order to write to it i was trying to do the same, since the description of the tool mentioned the possibility of adding new lines to a table.
in both cases i used a StockBindingSource to select the table from the database.

Comment: Could you post the code please, so I can see how you are getting your data, along with any variable declarations?

Comment: i get a couple of errors from that code: 1)Type SqlCommandBuilder is not defined
2) UpdateCommand is not a member of StockTableAdapter i would gladly use your first method but i do not understand how it is supposed to work

Comment: OK, I have changed the code example to explain all the steps. You will need to Import System.Data and System.Data.SqlClient: `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` `Imports System.Data` at the very top of the class file